# Why click event doesn't work in Internet Explorer using Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-9

I've already written a click method and it works fine for chrome and FF Webdrivers I'm trying to run my scripts for IE as well but the problem is that sometimes, click method does not work. It doesn't give back any error. That means it can find the relative elements.
Some of my code is as below:

```
time.sleep("a few seconds")  # Here I actually used explicit time wait
browser.switch_to_default_content()
button = browser.find_element_by_id("the_button_id")
button.click()
```

As I mentioned above, I don't get any errors and when I debug my scripts it passes the lines. Frankly, I don't know what's wrong with my code!

The tools version I use is:

> windows 7 ultimate 32 bit
>
> Internet Explorer 9
>
> IE_driver_server 32 bit version 2.44
>
> selenium version 2.44.0
>
> python 2.7
>   Thank you for your consideration

Comment: You don't really need to use this method, you can simply do browser.find_element_by_id("the_button_id").click() and that will work. That might actually solve your problem too, there's a chance that your method is starting up when the button isn't actually available to selenium yet.

Comment: Thanks Cronax. As you see, I've used exactly the lines you just mentioned but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to native events in IE11:

Visit http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/33394-webdriver-ie-click-doesn-t-seem-to-work

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER

capabilities['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True

capabilities['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True

capabilities.setdefault("nativeEvents", False)

driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get(url)